# Limiting the hover effect time in HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I limit the hover effect time in HTML? I want the hover styles to go away after three seconds.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="hover">Hover me!</div>

<style>
.hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background: green;
}

.hover:active {
  background: red;
  /* maximum hover time of 3 seconds */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a keyframe animation:

```css
.hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background: green;
}

.hover:hover {
  /* maximum hover time of 3 seconds */
  animation-name: hoverAnim;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes hoverAnim {
  from {
    background: red;
  }
  /* If you want to fade over time you can remove the 99% part */
  99% {
    background: red;
  }
  to {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">Hover me!</div>
```

If you don't want the instant switch, you can remove the 99% part.
Also, I changed `:active` to `:hover`, I assume that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that's what I meant from the start.

Answer (score -1):

You need do like this:

```css
.hover {
    transition-property: background;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    background: green;
}
.hover:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">Hover me!</div>
```

Comment: That delays adding them for 3 seconds. The question is asking how to *remove* them after 3 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    transition: 0s background-color;
    transition-delay:2s;
}
div:hover{
    background-color:Green;
}
```

```html
<div>hover</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but that's not what I meant, after hovering the element will change the background color, and the hover effect will disappear after a while.